# George "roots from" or "has roots in" the Campbell family: which is correct?

Tags: expressions, word-usage

Do we say "George roots from the Campbell family" or "George has roots in the Campbell family"?

Comment: "Root" as a verb can mean "to plant," as in *She rooted the aspidistra in a mixture of peat moss and Lego bricks."* Intransitively, "root" means to dig hungrily, as in *"The pig rooted in the humus and found a truffle."* Informally, it can mean to cheer for a favorite sport team. Your first example doesn't live in that company.

Answer (score 2):

Definitely not the first one, as 'root' in this context is a noun not a verb.

I'd say, "George is descended from the Campbell family"

Normally 'Roots' is used to describe a location, e.g. "George has roots in Scotland"

Comment: Personal(ly). ...

Comment: I decided that "" is probably better.. it removes unnecessarily redundant duplication.